# DynamicProxy returning null for PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is driving me batty. I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.2. Here's the line of code that's being weird:

```
var materialBt = prop.GetValue(material, null);
```

Where `prop` is a `PropertyInfo` that refers to a to-one association and `material` is a `DynamicProxies...` proxy for an entity. <strike>It *might* be relevant that `prop` is gotten by calling `type.GetProperties` on the *base* entity type, rather than on the DynamicProxy type.</strike> The same thing happens if I get the corresponding `PropertyInfo` from the proxy class, i.e. `material.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(material, null)` also returns `null`.

I have a breakpoint set immediately after this line. After it executes, `materialBt` is null. But, if I inspect `material` using the debugger, <strike>or call `prop.GetValue(material, null)` via the Immediate Window,</strike> the property in question has a value!

<strike>This happens *usually*. I have observed it sometimes returning the correct value for `materialBt`, but it seems this happens when I have a breakpoint further up in execution...so maybe it has "time" to get the value then? But this should be atomic, shouldn't it??</strike>

Is this a Lazy loading thing? <strike>Is the problem that the `PropertyInfo` is gotten from the base instead of the proxy class?</strike>

### Correction:

Playing around further, it seems that the value is returned properly only when I inspect it via the debugger, by hovering over `material` and expanding `base`. I found that, in fact, if I tried the Immediate Window before using the GUI inspector, I got `null` just as the running code returns. So the GUI inspector in the debugger is triggering the property to populate, it seems.

### More code:

```
private async Task Merge (Type type, object ephemeral, object material)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        //...
        if(IsModel(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            // A belongsTo relationship

-->         var materialBt = prop.GetValue(material, null);
```

Or, if you want [the full context...](https://github.com/SphtKr/JSONAPI.NET/blob/master/JSONAPI.EntityFramework/EntityFrameworkMaterializer.cs#L353)

Comment: Can you post more code? It might be some issue with `yield returns` or the evaluation time of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Stefan Just posted some additional info, might help. What bits of code are you interested in? The `prop` in question is a to-one association, so I don't think it has to do with `IEnumerables`.

Comment: Ok, the deferred execution time is not an issue here, I do wonder though: why is your method marked as `async`?

Comment: @Stefan further down there's a call to a `GetByIdAsync` method that makes DB calls, based on the EntityKey it digs up using the reflection here. That one's async so we have to `await` it.

Comment: AArrggghh!! The property in question wasn't marked `virtual`! But....that lets it still work *sometimes*???